# False theorem on particular case of Cauchy Sequences -- why is it wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

It goes as follows:

If $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$, $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy.
We have:
$$\forall \epsilon_0 > 0, \exists N : n > N \implies |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon_0$$
Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $m > n$. Consider:
$$|x_{m} - x_n| = | x_m - x_{m-1} + x_{m-1} -  x_{m-2} + ... + x_{n+1} - x_n |$$
By the triangle inequality,
$$| x_m - x_{m-1} + x_{m-1} -  x_{m-2} + ... + x_{n+1} - x_n | \leq |x_m - x_{m-1}| +...+ |x_{n+1} - x_n|$$
Then, for $n > N$, as $m>n>N$,
$$|x_m - x_{m-1}| +...+ |x_{n+1} - x_n| < (m-n+1) \epsilon_0$$
Hence, let $\epsilon_1 = (m-n+1) \epsilon_0$. Finally,
$$\forall \epsilon_1 > 0, \exists N: m,n > N \implies |x_m - x_n| < \epsilon_1$$
and the sequence is Cauchy, as intended.

This is untrue, the counterexample being the harmonic series. But each step of the way seems to make sense, I can't seem to figure out why it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion about $\epsilon_1 = (m-n+1) \epsilon_0$ depends on $m$ and $n$ ! That is your mistake.