# Prove that the sequence ($s_n$) is convergent if |$s_{n+1}$-$s_n$|<${1}/{2^n}$: Is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Last week we had our long exam in Advanced Calculus/Real Analysis and this question was asked: Prove that the sequence ($s_n$) is convergent if |$s_{n+1}$-$s_n$|<${1}/{2^n}$.

My proof goes like this,
Proof:
Note that ${1}/{2^n}$=|${1}/{2^n}$| for all natural numbers n. Thus, $|s_{n+1}-s_n|=|(s_{n+1}-s_n)-0|<{1}/{2^n}$ implies that ($s_{n+1}$-$s_n$) converges to $0$. Hence, for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a natural number $K$ s.t if $n \geq K$, then $|(s_{n+1}-s_n)-0|=|s_{n+1}-s_n|< \epsilon$. Then, $n+1,n \geq K$. And if we set $m:=n+1$, we have $|s_{m}-s_n|<\epsilon$. Hence, $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Therefore, by Cauchy Convergence Criterion, ($s_n$) is convergent.

QED

If I am wrong, can you please explain it why? I cannot get this question out of my head. Thank you.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Is my proof for this question right?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3134606/42969

Comment: @DumperDGarb the given question is similar to the form of Theorem 3.1.10 in Bartle and Sherbet's Introduction to Real Analysis, so I went to that route. Of course I do not know if I am right, so no need to be harsh in your comment :))

Comment: @DumperDGarb - the question implies that the OP is still new to the subject with perhaps a shaky grasp of convergence-style proofs. Don't assume beginners have a solid understanding of symbolic language which is represented in great extent in your comment. Furthermore your comment isn't really constructive either - it just says "I don't understand your proof" without saying much of what can be done to improve its clarity or improve its reasoning. As a result the OP is left feeling silly/insecure at having produced something seemingly confusing to others without having recourse for improvement.

Comment: @DumperDGarb You essentially just restated the question she has to prove in symbolic language. That's not really helpful...

Answer (score 7):

Your proof is not correct because $|s_{n+1}-s_n|\to 0$ dosen't implies that $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Indeed, take for example $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$$ Then, for all $n$, $$|s_{n+1}-s_n|\leq \frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0,$$
however, $(s_n)$ doesn't converges. Also, the problem in you proof, is that you took $m=n+1$, whereas $m$ should be unspecified (i.e. independent of $n$).

---

**Hint**

If $m>n$, then
$$|s_{m}-s_n|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Your proof cannot be right, because it is false if you replace $1/2^n$ with $1/n$, but your argument does not make use of that. For instance consider
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.
$$
Here $|s_{n+1}-s_n|<1/n$ but the sequence does not converge.

The usual argument you need is that, using the triangle inequality repeatedly,
$$
|s_{n+k}-s_n|\leq\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}|s_{n+j+1}-s_{n+j}|\leq\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac1{2^{n+j}}\leq\frac1{2^{n-1}} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

An addition to the other answers:

At the end you only show that $|s_m-s_n|<\epsilon$ for the specific value $m=n+1$ when $n$ is big enough. For a Cauchy sequence you shall have $|s_m-s_n|<\epsilon$ for *all* big enough $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

This proof is incorrect. Mainly, I think you've misunderstood the definition of what means for a sequence to be Cauchy. The sequence $(s_n)$ would be Cauchy if there exists a $K>0$ such that if $m, n > K$, then $|s_m - s_n| < \epsilon$. The only restriction on $m$ should be that it is greater than $K$. Unfortunately, you imposed an additional restriction - you explicitly defined $m$ to be $n+1$. That is not allowed. If the sequence was Cauchy, $m$ should be allowed to be $n+2$, for instance,  or $n+3$ or $n+4$ and so on... (hopefully you see what I mean). Any value of $m$ greater than $K$ should work (not just those values of $m$ that are exactly $1$ more than $n$). In essence, the value of $m$ should not depend on the value of $n$ that you chose.

Usually the way such a statement is approached is by using the Geometric series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1/2)^{k}$ to help us out. Since this series is convergent, its sequence of partial sums $T_N = \sum_{k=1}^N (1/2)^k$ is convergent and therefore Cauchy! Thus, there exists $K >0$ such that if $N, M >K$, then $|T_M - T_N| < \epsilon$. Choose, without loss of generality, numbers $M, N > (K + 1)$ so that $M > N$ (so, in particular, $M-1 \geq N-1 > K$ and the inequality $|T_{M-1} - T_{N-1}| < \epsilon$ still holds).

**Before moving on with the proof,** I want to explain the point I just made! Why am I assuming $M > N$? Did I not just say previously that the value of $M$ should have no other restriction other than $M > K$? Doesn't having $M > N$ impose an additional restriction?? Well, yes and no. Although it might *seem* like this is an additional restriction (which will be helpful for the purposes of the proof), it doesn't actually restrict the value $M$ can be for several reasons. First, if you choose any two numbers $M,N$, you're going to fall into either one of two cases: either both numbers you chose have the same value (i.e. $M = N$) or one number is larger than the other (say, $M > N$). In the case that both numbers have the same value ($M = N$), the result we're trying to prove is **trivial** since then $|S_M - S_N| = |S_N - S_N| = 0 < \epsilon$. Thus, the only way we can continue with this proof in a non-trivial way is if we consider the case where one number was larger than the other (i.e. $M > N$). Essentially, by imposing $M > N$, I've eliminated the trivial case and am considering the non-trivial case. However, the value of $M$ can be still be as larger or as small as I want as long as it's bigger than $N$. This differs significantly from your approach where $M$ always had to be *exactly* 1 more than $N$ (which was problematic).

Continuing with the proof, we observe that $$|S_M - S_N| = |(S_M - S_{M-1}) + (S_{M-1} - S_{M-2}) + \ldots + (S_{N+2} - S_{N+1}) + (S_{N+1} - S_N)|$$

(Depending on how large $M$ was, there might not actually be an $S_{M-2}$ term in the above telescoping sum, but I'm including it just so that you clearly see the manipulation that is happening).

Applying the triangle inequality numerous times to the right-hand side of the above equation, you can conclude $$|S_M - S_N| \leq \sum_{k=N}^{M-1} |S_{k+1} - S_{k}|$$

But, by hypothesis, $$\sum_{k=N}^{M-1} |S_{k+1} - S_{k}| < \sum_{k=N}^{M-1} \frac{1}{2^{k}} = |T_{M-1} - T_{N-1}| < \epsilon$$

But then the result $|S_M - S_N| < \epsilon$ immediately follows, showing the sequence is Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

**Some feedback**

It is not immediately clear that $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. The property $|s_{n+1} - s_{n}| < \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ is a little different than the property of a Cauchy sequence.

For a sequence $(s_n)$ to be a Cauchy sequence, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there must exist a natural number $N$ such that $|s_j - s_k| < \epsilon$ for all $j, k > N$.

Keep in mind that $j$ could be $k+1$ or even $k+1000$, so saying $|s_{n+1} - s_{n}| < \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ is not the same as saying $|s_{n+1000} - s_{n}| < \dfrac{1}{2^n}$.

However, we can show that $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Once we prove that $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, it follows that $(s_n)$ converges, since every Cauchy sequence converges.

---

**A proof that $(s_n)$ is convergent**

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence such that $|s_{n+1} - s_{n}| < \dfrac{1}{2^n}$.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_0 = s_0$ and $a_{n+1} = a_{n} - \dfrac{1}{2^n}$.

Let $(b_n)$ be a sequence such that $b_0 = s_0$ and $b_{n+1} = b_{n} + \dfrac{1}{2^n}$.

For $n \geq 1$ we have $\displaystyle a_n = s_0 - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{i}}$ and $\displaystyle b_n = s_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{i}}$.

Since a geometric series with ratio $r$ converges when $|r| < 1$, it follows that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converge as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

In fact, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = s_0 - 2$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = s_0 + 2$.

Now $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are both Cauchy sequences, since all convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists a natural number $N$ such that $|a_{j} - a_{k}| < \epsilon$ and $|b_{j} - b_{k}| < \epsilon$ for all $j, k > N$.

But $a_j - a_k < s_j - s_k < b_j - b_k$ for all $j, k > N$.

Thus $|s_j - s_k| < \epsilon$ for all $j, k > N$.

This means that $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

The sequence $(s_n)$ converges because all Cauchy sequences converge.

Answer (score 0):

The convergence of sequence $s_n$ is equivalent to the convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (s_{k}-s_{k-1}),$ where $s_0=0.$ Indeed the $n$th  partial sum.of the series is equal $$\sum_{k=1}^n(s_k-s_{k-1})=s_n$$ If a series is convergent, its general term, i.e. $s_k-s_{k-1},$ should tend to $0,$ but it this condition is not sufficient. In the OP case we have $$|s_{k}-s_{k-1}|\le {1\over 2^{k-1}}$$ so the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (s_{k}-s_{k-1})$ is convergent absolutely due to comparison test. Thus the sequence $s_n$ is convergent.